# Combining 2 vba codes over 2 different ranges into one statement

Tags: excel, vba

I can make one or the other of the below codes work, but need them both. The first locks cells in range upon data entry, the second inserts a date stamp when the final data entry in column D of each row is completed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Intersect(Range("A8:D5005"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="Midnight"
    xRg.Locked = True
    Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="Midnight"
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("D8:D5005")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
        Target.Offset.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Michelle, I've fixed your code indents so they show properly. On stackoverflow, the way to do that is that any line that begins with at least four spaces shows as code. If there are less than four spaces, it doesn't. Also, you'll want to edit this post and explain more clearly what "work" means. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you.  I have input your correction and now find that I get "Compile Error: Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change.  What I am trying to do is to prevent users from being able to overwrite their work and to also add a date and time stamp so that they do not need to input that.

Comment: Yes, of course, because you have `Worksheet_Change` in there twice. (Just to be clear, I didn't change the code, just fixed your formatting.) So, you're saying that as soon as a user leaves a cell within your target range, you want to lock the cell, preventing further input, and date and timestamp the item in a cell in the next column to the right. At least, that's what your code does, and I'm having trouble making sense of it, since your range has four columns. Where are you trying to put your time/datestamp exactly?

Comment: Before doing things in `Change` event handler, make sure you do not assign values to cells. If you do, you need to switch events off with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and in the end switch on with `Application.EnableEvents = True`. If you fail to do it, you'll get cyclic events. At some point Excel will stop it, but you can get incorrect results and waste of time (since Excel will be frozen in recursion).

Comment: Is it not possible to combine my 2 functions into one code?  If so, I will use the cell protection upon data entry code and instruct users to press shortcut keys to enter date and then time in columns E and F, respectively.  My users are very limited as a group in their skills, so that's what's driving this.  As example, here is current instruction at top of sheet: Scan your barcode>enter gallons>press Tab>enter Sugar Content>press Tab>Type P for Picked Up or D for Delivered>press Enter. It automatically moves to the next data entry line for them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of the structure of your worksheet, so here are the assumptions for my response. You only want the user to modify cells in the range "A8:D5005" … and somewhere on the sheet you want to record date/timestamp changes for cells changed.

So I would start by protecting the sheet by going to the Excel "Review" ribbon (not in VBA), and setting up an editable range as follows.

[image: Review ribbon]

Before you close the dialog box, click on Protect Sheet so that the rest of the sheet is password protected.

[image: Allow Users to Edit Range]

Once you've done this … you can use something like the code below to record the date/timestamps. In this example … I record them in columns to the right of your editable range (given your editable data is only to Column D).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim vIntersect As Variant
    Set vIntersect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A8:D5005"))
    If Not vIntersect Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="Midnight"
        Target.Offset(0, 5) = Now
        Target.Offset(0, 5).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        Target.Worksheet.Protect Password:="Midnight"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, all.  Below is a screen shot with user instructions at the top that I think will provide clarity.  It also shows result of code Techno Dabbler code.  Asking users to input a password to complete their data entry is a no go, so I am trying to both protect A8:D5005 upon data entry and also add timestamp to column E. Is this not possible?   I know that I can successfully use the data entry protection code, so should I give up on combining these functions and have users insert time and date in columns E and F, respectively, with shortcut keys?

Comment: Thank you, Techo Dabbler.  I prefer not to ask users to input a password to enter data and that solution would retain their ability to accidentally overwrite existing data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still guessing a bit exactly what you're trying to do … but here is way to allow your users enter four data points ... and then to press button to add the data points to a protected list … and includes a time stamp.

First setup 4 data entry cells in A4 through to D4 by using the Format Cell option, make sure for these cells that **Locked** is **unchecked** on the Protection tab.

Next create a button and link the button to the following code:

```
Sub ButtonCode()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="A"
    Range("A7:E7").Insert xlShiftDown
    Range("A4:D4").Copy Range("A7:D7")
    Range("E7") = Now()
    Range("A7:E7").Interior.Color = rgbLightBlue
    Range("A7:E7").Font.Color = rgbBlack
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="A"
End Sub
```

As a once only step, protect the worksheet; my example consistently uses a password of "A". Note that your users will not need to enter the password at any time.

Once the sheet is setup, when the button is clicked, the code unlocks the sheet (allowing it to make edits), it move the existing data data down, copy the new data points to the top of the list, adds timestamp and some minimal formatting. It then re-enables protection so that the user can't overwrite the existing entries.

The screenshot below gives you an idea of what it might look like, including showing that A4:D4 need to be unlocked.

[image: screen example]

Maybe not the implementation direction you were thinking of … but the principles included in this example might work for you. All the best.

Comment: Thank you for another fine answer, Techno Dabbler.  Setting up the sheet is no problem, but good to see those reminders.  I don't want to use a button, so will try to get this code to launch upon hitting Enter at column D.